# Adding multiple tags to model

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I have the following model:

```
class Investor(Profile):
ROLE = (
    ('AN', 'Angel Investor'),
    ('VC', 'Venture Capital'),
    ('SC', 'Seed Capital')
)
role = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='AN', choices=ROLE)
min_inv = models.DecimalField(
    default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2,
    verbose_name='Minimum Investments per year')
max_inv = models.DecimalField(
    default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2,
    verbose_name='Maximum investments per year')
no_startups = models.IntegerField(
    default=0, verbose_name='Number of investments per year')
rating_sum = models.FloatField(default=0)
no_raters = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to add multiple tags to this model.
- Category
- Stage
- Funding

I want investors to be assigned to multiple categories, stages, and funding. 
So an investor can be tied to multiple Categories
and multiple Stages
and multiple Funding types.

How can I edit the model to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you just add [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationships for the connected models??

```
class Investor(Profile):
  ROLE = (
    ('AN', 'Angel Investor'),
    ('VC', 'Venture Capital'),
    ('SC', 'Seed Capital')
  )
  role = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='AN', choices=ROLE)
  min_inv = models.DecimalField(
    default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2,
    verbose_name='Minimum Investments per year')
  max_inv = models.DecimalField(
    default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2,
    verbose_name='Maximum investments per year')
  no_startups = models.IntegerField(
    default=0, verbose_name='Number of investments per year')
  rating_sum = models.FloatField(default=0)
  no_raters = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  categories = models.ManyToMany(Category)
  stages = models.ManyToMany(Stage)
  fundings = models.ManyToMany(Funding)
```

Using manytomany you can then assign stages

```
investor = Investor.objects.all()[0]
investor.categories.add(category_instance_one, category_instance_two)
investor.categories.all() # retrieves all categories that this investor has
```